# HTML5 canvas game not working in IE

Tags: html, canvas, javascript, javascript-framework

I'm working on a HTML5 canvas game using a JavaScript library called Propulsionjs.com. The preview can be seen here: http://druls.com/balloon/. To enable the canvas element in IE I have included a few of libraries like extcanvas, still some part of the game is not working properly.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me out? As I found out sprite elements are not working. Can anyone help me solving this issue? The source code here: http://druls.com/balloon/balloons.zip.

Comment: The two `html5.js` files are identical. Why not remove one and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on line 1567: `value.call(value,value);`

`value` is undefined and IE9 is stopping execution.